# Validating forms involving textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery technology to validate web forms(I am actually learning now). After downloading and referencing the files in my code, TEXTAREA stubbornly refused to be validated even after assigning it REQUIRED class attribute. Pls could someone help. Apologies, if it's trivial.
Here's the code:

```
<script type ="text/JavaScript" src = "jquery.js"></script>
<script type ="text/JavaScript" src ="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type ="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#reg").validate(); 
})// end of ready()
```

From Code:

```
<form id = 'reg' method ='post' action =''>
<label for 'username'>User Name **</label>
 <input type ='text' name ='username' id ='usN' class = 'required' title = "Enter Your name"><br/>
 <label for 'Address'> Address **</label>
<input type ='text' id ='addr' class = 'required' title = "Enter Your Address"><br/>
<label for 'comment'>Comment Below **</label>
br/> <textarea id ='comm' rows =5, cols = 18 class ='required' title = 'Make a comment'></textarea><br/>
<input type ='submit' id = 'button1' value = 'SEND'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a unique `name` attribute to each input/textarea element.

[Markup recommendations](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference#link-markup-recommendations)

> The name attribute is required for input elements, the validation plugin doesn't work without it.

Comment: I expanded the fields to include menu:<select>...</select> reflecting the above answer. Every other field behaved well apart from the menu. What could be wrong? @GUL

Comment: Without knowing what you did it's difficult to help you. Maybe you have first option always selected and then validation passes. If first option contains just a comment like `Please choose one option` you should give it empty value `<select name="select" required><option value="">Please choose</option><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option>...</select>`